# how to run sencha touch examples in iOS simulator

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2, ios-simulator

I installed [sencha touch](https://www.sencha.com/products/touch/) and [sencha touch command](http://www.sencha.com/products/sencha-cmd/download) and was able to view the examples in localhost.
But How do I run these examples in iOS simulator?

I tried below commands from with in the examples directory on iMac
from directory: touch-2.3.1/examples/kitchensink
`sencha app package run packager.json`

```
User-iMac:list-horizontal yuyutsu$ sencha app package run packager.json 
Sencha Cmd v4.0.4.84
[ERR] 
[DEBUG] Session could not be started: Error Domain=DTiPhoneSimulatorErrorDomain Code=1 
"The application that opened iOS Simulator failed to send all of the required information 
(sessionUUID, sdkRoot, deviceInfo)." UserInfo=0x7fe4f0d0ce40 {NSLocalizedDescription=The application 
that opened iOS Simulator failed to send all of the required information (sessionUUID, sdkRoot,
 deviceInfo)., DTiPhoneSimulatorUnderlyingErrorCodeKey=-1}
The application was successfully packaged

[ERR] stbuild exited with non-zero code : 1
```

or from another app, directory: touch-2.3.1/examples/list-horizontal
Also tried running `sencha app build -run native`.
It failed with

```
/Users/yuyutsu/work/Software/mobile/Sencha/touch-2.3.1/examples/kitchensink/.sencha/app/packager-impl.xml:83: /Users/yuyutsu/work/Software/mobile/Sencha/touch-2.3.1/examples/kitchensink/resources/loading does not exist
```

I have Xcode **5**. OS X version **10.9.2**. I am able to run the native XCode projects in simulator using XCode. 
Any idea on how can I run the sencha examples in iOS simulator? Is there a document which has the steps?

Comment: Do you use phonegap and did you configure UUID of your device?

Comment: I thought the examples from sencha download were ready baked and could run them in simulator using `sencha app package run packager.json`. I did not use any other tool yet.

Comment: Try to compile with `sudo sencha app build native` and then run the XCode project.

Comment: @Zistoolen - I tried the above build native command with sudo and it did not help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Failure to launch iOS simulator could be because of the below bug mentioned in [sencha forum](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?285446-how-to-run-sencha-touch-examples-in-iOS-simulator)
*"There is currently a bug open SDKTOOLS-783 where Sencha Native packager fails to locate Xcode 5.1 and thus unable to run in simulator."*

I will try Phonegap/Cordova and post my observations.

Answer (score 1):

One very easy way (if you don't need device api) is to build the webapp through Sencha CMD and navigate in iOS Simulators Safari to the index.html file. You can do "add to Homescreen" and if you click the icon on your homescreen now you get the app in fullscreen.
The big advantage is that you can do really quick builds, but it does not fit always, because it's just the webapp, not the native one.

If you need to package your app native (e.g. for Device API) you can follow this guide: http://frightanic.com/software-development/sencha-touch-native-packaging-for-ios-done-right/

Answer (score 1):

As it is running on localhost, you can simply check on simulators by using the same urls as on browser

[iPhone 4](http://iphone4simulator.com/)

[iPhone 5](http://iphone5simulator.com/)

Also, you can try Intel XDK, it has inbuilt iPhone simultors. It is easy to use. Simply put application and run.

[Intel XDK](http://xdk-software.intel.com/)

Or you can try packaging it in native iOS so that you can run in Xcode and see on Xcode simulator your app working. For that you can use Phonegap, refer link

http://docs-origin.sencha.com/touch/2.3.2/#!/guide/cordova-section-iOSNote

Also,

http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.3.2/#!/guide/native_provisioning

Hope this helps you with your problem.